# Android Icons, how to specify?

Tags: android

Where do I put my icons in my android file structure, and how do I reference them in the manifest xml?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put them in your drawables folders under res.

There are three "types" of drawables, hi-res, med-res and low-res respectively.
Each gets their own folder:

- drawable-hdpi
- drawable-mdpi
- drawable-ldpi

You can reference them in your code directly by using

```
R.drawable.(icon name)
```

If you want to use them in your XML files, use this instead:

```
@drawable/(icon name)
```

As long as your drawables have the same name in all the folders, Android will pick the right one to show depending on the DPI of your device's screen.

More info about drawables here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html

For those reading back later, the question was about the launcher icons.
Their sizes are as follows:

- ldpi: 36x36 px
- mdpi: 48x48 px
- hdpi: 64x64 px
- xhdpi: 96x96 px

You can find more about the launcher icons here: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_launcher.html#size

The article also gives some do's and don'ts about launcher icons. Might be worth a look.

Comment: Thanks, but what size should each icon be for each drawable folder?

Comment: Already posted in the answer below, but: (Assuming you still mean the launcher icons(those in the app menu) )

Ldpi: 36x36
mdpi: 48x48
hdpi: 64x64
xhdpi: 96x96

You can find that here: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_launcher.html#size

The article also gives some do's and don'ts about launcher icons. Might be worth a look.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean a main icon for your application? If not please disregard this answer.
Under res create a drawable folder and place your icon there.
In the androidmanifest.xml you'll need to add the following code

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/logo" android:label="@string/app_name">
```

You can exchange the logo to fit your icon filename.

Comment: Yes this is what I mean, thanks. What size shoudl the icon be in the res folder?

Comment: Ldpi: 36x36
mdpi: 48x48
hdpi: 64x64
xhdpi: 96x96

You can find that here: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_launcher.html#size

The article also gives some do's and don'ts about launcher icons. Might be worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

In the relevent drawable folder e.g. res/drawable-hdpi